# MediaplayerElement PosterSource

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm trying to show a different PosterSource with the MediaplayerElement (UWP) for every video in a playlist. The first playlist item is fine, with the poster showing. When I choose next or previous a "new" poster is not shown.

(MSDN) The PosterSource is displayed in the following situations:
When a valid source is not set. For example, Source is not set, Source is set to Null, or the source is invalid (as is the case when a MediaFailed event fires).
While media is loading. For example, a valid source is set, but the MediaOpened event has not fired yet.
While media is streaming to another device.
When the media is audio only.

I have playList.MaxPlayedItemsToKeepOpen = 0 - which should insure that the file is reloaded at next and prev.

I have also set the MediaPlayer source to null...and reset it so the posters should reload and show. No Luck.

Comment: Could you please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: As you play video's on the playlist - only the first one in the playlist will show the poster. (Even if you change the path) The others  just start at the movie beginning (No poster first).